# Is there some utility to convert MATIC into ETH

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, polygon

I want to convert MATIC into ETH on my frontend so that I can store the value as ETH in my smart contract. Is there a utility to do so.

Also is my approach of first MATIC into ETH and then storing in the smart contract correct or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can swap WMATIC to ETH on QuickSwap. SushiSwap or others, programmatically. Whatever you can do from your MetaMask on a website, you can do it programmatically as well.

[Here is a list of automated market maker (AMM) decentralised exchanges (DEXes) on Polygon that allow you to do the swap](https://tradingstrategy.ai/trading-view/polygon).

[Here are some programmatic examples of how to do the swap using smart contracts](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/eth-hentai#uniswap-v2-trade-example). Depending on the DEX, they give you a frontend JS SDK that helps to construct the swap transaction.